# Python for loop iterates over list

Tags: python, for-loop

If I input `"apple Pie is Yummy"` I want: `['Pie','Yummy'] ['apple','is']`

I get: `[] ['apple', 'Pie', 'is', 'Yummy']`.

If I input `"Apple Pie is Yummy"` I want: `['Apple','Pie','Yummy'] ['is']`

I get: `['Apple', 'Pie', 'is', 'Yummy'] []`

It's behaving like my conditional operator is only read once during first iteration of for loop then additional iterations don't evaluate the condition.

```
str = input("Please enter a sentence: ")

chunks = str.split()

# create tuple for use with startswith string method
AtoZ = ('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z')

# create empty lists to hold data
list1 = []
list2 = []

for tidbit in chunks:
    list1.append(tidbit) if (str.startswith(AtoZ)) else list2.append(tidbit)

print(list1)
print(list2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are testing the wrong variable; you wanted to check `tidbit`, not `str`:

```
list1.append(tidbit) if (tidbit.startswith(AtoZ)) else list2.append(tidbit)
```

I'd instead use Python's own `str.isupper()` test instead to just test the first character of `tidbit`:

```
list1.append(tidbit) if tidbit[0].isupper() else list2.append(tidbit)
```

Next, just create the two lists with list comprehensions, because using a conditional expression for its side effects is pretty horrible:

```
list1 = [tidbit for tidbit in chunks if tidbit[0].isupper()]
list2 = [tidbit for tidbit in chunks if not tidbit[0].isupper()]
```

Comment: Thank you, I missed the obvious.

Answer (score 1):

```
chunks = raw_input("Enter a sentence: ").split()
list1 = [chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk[0].isupper()]
list2 = [chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk not in list1]
```

Comment: Unless `list1` is tiny, the creation of `list2` has a performance disadvantage over `[chunk for chunk in chunks if not chunk[0].isupper()]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.isupper()` here:

```
def solve(strs):

    dic={"cap":[],"small":[]}

    for x in strs.split():
        if x[0].isupper():
            dic["cap"].append(x)
        else:    
            dic["small"].append(x)

    return dic["small"],dic["cap"]



In [5]: solve("apple Pie is Yummy")
Out[5]: (['apple', 'is'], ['Pie', 'Yummy'])

In [6]: solve("Apple Pie is Yummy")
Out[6]: (['is'], ['Apple', 'Pie', 'Yummy'])
```

**help(str.upper)**:

```
In [7]: str.isupper?
Type:       method_descriptor
String Form:<method 'isupper' of 'str' objects>
Namespace:  Python builtin
Docstring:
S.isupper() -> bool

Return True if all cased characters in S are uppercase and there is
at least one cased character in S, False otherwise.
```